# Are co.uk domains and the likes subdomains?

Tags: domains, subdomain

I was wondering, are co.uk domains and others with an additional dot subdomains? If not, why not, and if so, can you create sub-sub domains?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`uk` is a TLD (top level domain). `uk` is the ccTLD (country code TLD) for the United Kingdom. All `uk` domains are controlled by [Nominet](http://www.nominet.org.uk/). Nominet imposes additional restrictions on the registration of these domains. No-one can register a subdomain directly under the TLD `uk`. They must register a domain under one of the defined *subdomains* `.co.uk`, `.org.uk` and one or two others.

Yes, `co` is a subdomain of `uk` in the case of `.co.uk`. `co` is a SLD (second level domain).

In the case of `example.co.uk` then `example` (a third level domain) is a subdomain of `co` (a second level domain or SLD) which is a subdomain of `uk` (a top level domain or TLD).

`foo.bar.example.co.uk` - `foo` (fifth level domain) is a subdomain of `bar`, which is a subdomain of...

You can have many many subdomains (upto 127 I seem to recall), however, there are additional limits as to the length of the full domain which you would probably exceed first.

Answer (score 5):

`.co.uk` and the likes are country code second level domains (**ccSLD**).

From [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code_second-level_domain) -

> A country code second-level domain (ccSLD) is a second-level domain to a country code top-level domain. A ccSLD may be reserved by the domain name registry for the registration of third-level domains or assigned to a third party as a subdomain.
>   Many country code domain registries implement domain name classes at the second level underneath their ccTLD, such as are present in the original generic top-level domains com, net, and org, which were intended for commercial entities, network operators, and non-profit organizations, respectively.

And yes, you can create sub-sub domains, or multiple level subdomains. Check out this question from [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/questions/278295/subdomain-of-a-subdomain)